# How to stop audio when I click another image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to play audio when I click to image. But when I click another image are playing both. I need to stop or pause first sound to play the new sound.

I don't want to use `<audio>` tag in html as soon as possible; not for something special just to get the challenge.

I am trying this:

```
HTML:

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img id="beach" src="./images/beach.jpeg" alt="" >
    </div>
    <div class="box">
     <img id="river" src="./images/river.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
     <img id="mountains" src="./images/mountain.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img id="rain" src="./images/rain.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
     <img id="jungle" src="./images/jungle.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img id="fire" src="./images/fire.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
Javascript: 

window.addEventListener('load',
    function () {
        let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
        images.forEach(image =>{
            image.addEventListener("click", playAudio);
                  
        })
        
    }, false);


function playAudio (event){
    
    let imgName = event.currentTarget.id;
    let audioPlay = new Audio(`./sounds/${imgName}.wav`);

    audioPlay.onloadedmetadata = function (eSound){
        
        eSound.currentTarget.loop = true;
        eSound.currentTarget.play()
       
    }
console.log(event)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable, e.g. `currentAudio`, to check if there is audio playing. When the audio starts, set the `currentAudio` to the audio target, then when you call the function again it checks to see if it is set to null if it is not then it will stop the audio and reset it to null

```
let currentAudio = null;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    images.forEach(image => {
        image.addEventListener("click", playAudio);
    });
}, false);

function playAudio(event) {
    if (currentAudio) {
        currentAudio.pause();
        currentAudio = null;
    }

    let imgName = event.currentTarget.id;
    let audioPlay = new Audio(`./sounds/${imgName}.wav`);

    audioPlay.onloadedmetadata = function (eSound) {
        eSound.currentTarget.loop = true;
        eSound.currentTarget.play();
        currentAudio = eSound.currentTarget;
    };

    console.log(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use check variable for this to keep track whether audio is playing or not,
example -

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    let currentlyPlayingAudio = null;

    images.forEach(image => {
        image.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            playAudio(event, currentlyPlayingAudio);
        });
    });
}, false);

function playAudio(event, currentlyPlayingAudio) {
    let imgName = event.currentTarget.id;
    let audioPlay = new Audio(`./sounds/${imgName}.wav`);

    if (currentlyPlayingAudio) {
        currentlyPlayingAudio.pause();
        currentlyPlayingAudio.currentTime = 0;
    }

    audioPlay.onloadedmetadata = function (eSound) {
        eSound.currentTarget.loop = true;
        eSound.currentTarget.play();
    };

    currentlyPlayingAudio = audioPlay;
    console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn´t work for me, still playing all sounds togheter